# PHP Undefined variable in a closure

Tags: php

The following snippet returns a bunch of input fields but I'm unable to set their values because $data is undefined (it being inside a closure).

```
$row = array_map(function($n) {
    $name = sprintf('point[%0d]', $n+1);
    $value = $data['measurements'][$n];
    return form_input($name, $value, "class='input-mini'");
}, range($i*6, $i*6+5));
```

I know global variables are not cool. What's the best way to get around this?

Comment: Use `function($n) use ($data) {`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Inheriting variables from the parent scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-167)

```
$row = array_map(function($n) use ($data) {
    $name = sprintf('point[%0d]', $n+1);
    $value = $data['measurements'][$n];
    return form_input($name, $value, "class='input-mini'");
}, range($i*6, $i*6+5));
```