# Undefined variable: toemail Laravel mail issue

Tags: laravel, email

I am going to send mail using laravel

so i have

```
$mailD   = DB::table('users')->select('name','email')->where('id', $request->input('Appraiserid'))->get();
$toemail = $mailD[0]->email;
```

When i echo $toemail it will echo value.

And when i send mails

```
if ($update) {
    $datamail = [
        'title'   => $getcycle[0]->Heading,
        'Heading' => 'Form Reject',
        'Name'    => $mailD[0]->name,
        'email'   => $mailD[0]->email
    ];

    Mail::send('voyager::users.send', ["data1" => $datamail], function ($message) {
        $message->subject('Form reject');
        $message->from('test@gmail.com');
        $message->to($toemail);
    });
}
```

Got an error like

> ErrorException in Users.php line 631: Undefined variable: toemail

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show us the full code?\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Undefined variable in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382460/php-undefined-variable-in-a-closure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for more [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail)

```
Mail::send('voyager::users.send', ["data1"=>$datamail], function ($message) use ($toemail) {
            $message->subject('Form reject');
            $message->from('test@gmail.com');
            $message->to($toemail);
});
```